# For what finite cardinalities of $Y$ is $\mathbb{R}^2 - Y$ a topological group?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

I am working on the following problem: for what cardinalities (of $Y$) can $\mathbb{R}^2 - Y$ be a topological group if $Y$ must be finite? My intuition is telling me this somehow involves considering a wedge of circles, but I am not 100% sure on the details. Would anyone be able to confirm this, and if I am wrong, to put me on the right track? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: [The fundamental group of a topological group is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686496/the-fundamental-group-of-a-topological-group-is-abelian/686923)

The question in the body of the question is different from the title though do you want $\mathbf R^3$ or $\mathbf R^2$.

Comment: My apologies for the typo, should be $\mathbb{R}^2$. So using the hint, I should try and find the smallest cardinality such that the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2 - Y$ is no longer abelian?

Comment: @CBBAM yes that sounds good! And like you said before its easier to think of retracting to wedges of circles

Comment: Thank you! So based on that, I am thinking that for $|Y| > 1$ the space cannot be a topological group. My reason is that for any two points, we will obtain a space that is homotopic to the figure 8, which is known to not be abelian. Is something like this correct? Sorry I am still getting the hang of this material.

Comment: @CBBAM yes! That sounds goods to me :)

Comment: Thank you very much!!